# @Url.Action in ASP.NET MVC to action formaction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I've spent most of the day chasing my tail on this. There are many wonderful suggestions out there, but none that address all my problems:

We have an existing website, where someone's linked button href's to absolute addresses, and I am trying to figure out a way to do that. I've got most of it, but one line with a styled button and formaction just won't work. The original code is like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post))
{
   // ... a <div>, then a stack of buttons, that I've converted to
   // <a href="@Url.Action(.... and those buttons work

   <button class="submit" id="Save" value="Save" formaction="Model/Action" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>

    // ... a stack of more buttons and checkboxes, that are all working...
}...
```

I need to retain the glyphicon as the button image, and the formaction when the button is clicked.

If I change the button to an `<input>`, I lose the `<span>` and hence the glyphicon.

If I call an `@Url.Action()` in the button, like this:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Action","Model")'" class="btn.... etc.
```

It doesn't seem to submit anything in the post. If I specify the Action and Model in the BeginForm(), I get a resource not found, because it's trying to find the View, instead of just the action...

So, what *is* the proper way to change this button with the absolute link into an ASP.NET MVC something, that will fire the action in the controller **and** is stylable as a button with a glyphicon as image?

Comment: AFAIK, `BeginForm()` doesn't require a view. It just needs to point to a Controller and an Action in that controller.

Comment: thanks @LarsKristensen... I thought so, too, but when I set the action and controller in the BeginForm() I get a "resource not found" error, even though it's there when I call it via the formaction

Comment: The problem seems to be the `formaction="Model/Action"` attribute. Do you have multiple submit buttons (not just other buttons, but buttons that submit the form)? If not, you could remove this attribute.

Comment: why dont u use ajax to post the data ? on button click call a jquery function and do a post action ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the `formaction="Model/Action"` attribute on the submit button. This attribute is used to point to a different Controller and Action, than the one defined in the `Html.BeginForm()` method. This is useful if you have multiple submit buttons in the same form, that should submit to different actions.

In your case, there is no Controller and Action defined in your `Html.BeginForm()` method, so the `formaction` attribute should point to a Controller action that accepts an argument matching the type of your model. Right now, it points `"Model/Action"`. You get an `HTTP 404` error, because you either don't have a controller called `ModelController`, or that controller doesn't have an action called `Action`. Change the controller or action part of the `formaction` attribute to point to the correct controller or action.

Comment: thank you @LarsKristensen. Thanks to you, I am a big step forward. The action was there, but for some reason didn't fire, so I re-write it in the controller and now it fires - perhaps a typo? Anyhoo... I now have another issue, and that is that the data is not being passed on. It works via the "formaction" in the button tag, but if I call @Url.Action("Action","Model") it fails to pass the data on... I'll do some more reading on this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) 
If you need to submit your model to different actions, you can't use `@Url.Action` as this will produce a HTTP GET request when the link is clicked, and you can't (or rather, shouldn't) include data in the GET request body. So you need several submit-buttons that point to different actions. I can try to make an example of this, but I won't be able to do it today.

Comment: Thank you, @LarsKristensen, I saw some other links with information on the multiple submit scenario. I'm good! :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, thank you to @LarsKristensen for helping me solve this: Just for my own reference and anyone else that gets stuck, here my conversion:

From:

```
<button type="submit" 
        id="Save" 
        value="Save" 
        formaction="/somecontroller/someaction"
        class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save">
    </span>
</button>
```

which had the absolute link, I now have:

```
@using{Html.BeginForm("someaction","somecontroller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // ... lots of other HTML and form elements

    <button type="submit"
            id= "Save"
            value = "Save"
            onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("someaction","somecontroller","Save")'" 
             class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save">
        </span>
    </button>
    // .. lots of other HTML and form elements
}
```

With one caveat. This will only work with a single submit button.